# getExtraMethod() in ZipEntry class returning null, where as getName() method is returning the filename correctly

Tags: java, zip

```java
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(byte[])); //input is byte []

ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();

while (ze != null) {
    String fileName = ze.getName();

    String extension = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("."), fileName.length());
    if (".xml".equalsIgnoreCase(extension)) {
         Document oldSdoDocument = builder.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(ze.getExtra()));
         //compare xml content
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour], read [ask], and go through the [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) to improve the quality of your question.

Comment: [`getExtra()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#getExtra()) returns *the extra field data for the entry, or null if none*. What had you expected to get from it?

Comment: If you are trying to read the data for the zip entry, read it from the input stream instead of using `getExtra()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to fetch the file content from the byte[], using ZipInputStream and then ZipEntry.getExtra(), I was not getting the file content. Instead I recreated the zip file in a temp location, and then used ZipFile to read the zip file, and for the file content, I used zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry). Once I have the inputsream of a file, I can do any type of manupulations to it.

Answer (score 0):

The [getExtra()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html#getExtra()) method does not retrieve the file content in the zip file, but returns the value of the *extra* field in the zip entry.  The [extra field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#Extra_field) is this:

> .ZIP file format includes an extra field facility within file headers, which can be used to store extra data not defined by existing ZIP specifications, and which allow compliant archivers that do not recognize the fields to safely skip them. Header IDs 0–31 are reserved for use by PKWARE. The remaining IDs can be used by third-party vendors for proprietary usage.

It looks like you simply want to read XML files in the ZIP and parse them, so instead of using the extra field, read the data from the zip input stream itself:

```
ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(byte[])); //input is byte []

ZipEntry ze = zis.getNextEntry();
while (ze != null) {
    String fileName = ze.getName();

    String extension = fileName.substring(fileName.indexOf("."), fileName.length());
    if (".xml".equalsIgnoreCase(extension)) {
         Document oldSdoDocument = builder.parse(zis);
         //compare xml content
    }
    ze = zis.getNextEntry();
}
```

Comment: I will have other files as well inside that zip example .pdf files as well. So I can not use zipInputStream directly for parsing. Even though I have only one xml file inside zip and I'm using zipInputStream directly for parsing then, I will get an exception like premature end of the file.